# cordova firebase plugin for ios 10 +

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement firebase cloud messaging in iOS cordova app.

I tried `cordovan-plugin-fcm` plugin 
It works in iOS 9 but not working with iOS 10.

My question is which was the best cordova firebase plugin to implement push notification? Is it iOS 9 or 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this. https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Then from your firebase account, Try to send notifications. It will work.

Comment: hi i already implemented this plugin  it work in ios 9 not in 10

Comment: What is actually going on in iOS 10? Can You let me know if you are getting some error?

Comment: not getting any error   not receiving push notification / is any native code required  since i am not an ios developer?

Comment: can you explain  with example ?

Comment: Are you getting the device token?

Comment: Then the problem is with certificates. Try http://pushtry.com/ to send notification to the device token you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works on simulator with ios 9.3 but if if try the same on simuator with ios 10.3 there is no message.
This is my code:

```
    FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token){
    if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == "amazon-fireos" ){
        sendPushRegistration(token, 'android');
    } else {
        sendPushRegistration(token, 'ios');
    }
  });

  FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token){
    if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == "amazon-fireos" ){
        sendPushRegistration(token, 'android');
    } else {
        sendPushRegistration(token, 'ios');
    }
  });

  FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    alert('onNotification');
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }else{
      //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }
 });
```

I get a token in the getToken function. But the onNotification function isn`t called in ios 10.3, in ios 9.3 it works.
Plugin is cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin" and the message was send by firebase console to one device.